# <button> versus <input type="image">

Tags: html, accessibility

This is for an "Add to basket" control for which one of my colleagues has designed a nice graphic.  Obviously it should generate a post request, which a simple hyperlink isn't going to do.

Amazon achieves it using an image input.  But what are the pros and cons of

```
<input type="image" src="atb.png" alt="Add to Basket" />
```

versus

```
<button type="submit"><img src="atb.png" alt="Add to Basket" /></button>
```

(and using CSS to control the appearance)?

I guess it boils down to these questions:

- Do all browsers, graphical and non-graphical, succeed in their duty to make image inputs keyboard-accessible?  (Or, in the case of keyboardless devices, make them accessible by whatever the means of input is?)
- What browsers are there that don't support `<button>`?
- What other advantages/disadvantages are there of each?
- Are there any other possible approaches with their own advantages (besides forgetting it and just using a plain submit)?

Answer (score 2):

They *should* be equivalent. For styling purposes, I find button tags are more flexible if you change things in the future.

**But:** IE has a bug/feature where the value of a button or input is set to equal the innerHTML. This can cause problems if your server side code needs this to be a particular value.

Unless you need the additional styling flexibility of `<button>` go with `<input type="image">` so you don't need to deal with IE's quirks.

Comment: Side note: The IE bug has been fixed in IE8 Standards Mode.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that IE bug too.  We may end up using only one such button per form, IWC this won't be a problem.  But I can see the possibility of throwing something into the innerHTML for the server-side code to detect.

But `<input type="button">`?  Is this a typo, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Input type="Image" supports the Disabled attribute and the browser will Grey out the image for you. With Type=Button you'd have to provide an alternate grey image.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN:

> When you submit a form using a button created with `<input type="image">`, two extra data points are submitted to the server automatically by the browser — x and y.

So one difference is that the `input[type=image]` transmits the coordinates of the pixel you clicked. It is 2019 and `button` is well supported so personally I use it unless I really need `x, y` - lets say, if the image is a map and I want to know where the user clicked in the map.